# How to append to a file using android Storage access framework?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

How can I use storage access framework to get a FileOutputStream to append to a file? The following code overwrites the file

```
void write(Uri uri){
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor=getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri,"w");
            if(descriptor!=null) {
                FileOutputStream op=new FileOutputStream(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                op.write("test string".getBytes());
                op.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I know doing it with java.io.File using `FileOutputStream(File file,boolean append)`

But I can't see `FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor fd,boolean append)`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating FileOutputStream from

`FileOutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());`

you can directly get OutputStream using

`context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(yourUri, "wa");`

and provide this following modes `w` `wa` `rw` or `rwt`
and to append  existing file  use `wa`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append to the file, you need to use access mode **"wa"** instead of "w" in this call:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor =
    getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
```

Comment: only  ```r``` ```w``` ```t``` are supported using both ```w``` ```a``` throws an Exception